# Accessing Objects Key:Value Pair in Function

Tags: javascript, function, object, nan, multiplication

When I run this code I cannot get it to console.log the answer I am looking for. I get NaN when I run the code. How do I get this function to multiply the objects mysteryNumber value and return the result?

```
const mysteryNumberObject = {
  mysteryNumber: 5,
};

function multiplyMysteryNumberByFive(mysteryNumberObject) {
  for(let key in mysteryNumberObject) {
    console.log(key * 5);
  }
};

multiplyMysteryNumberByFive(mysteryNumberObject);
```

Comment: `console.log(mysteryNumberObject[key] * 5);` would have worked, assuming it will always be a `Number`. `key` is `mysteryNumber` so * 5 is `NaN`. You need to reference the object[key] in order to access the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

The only key in the object is `"magicNumber"`, multiplying that with 5 makes no sense. I think you want to get the values of the object instead:

```
function multiplyMysteryNumberByFive(mysteryNumberObject) {
  for(let value of Object.values(mysteryNumberObject)) {
    console.log(value * 5);
   }
}
```

Comment: I already submitted the answer I came up with and it was correct for the course. What you are doing doesn’t solve what the problem asked.

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating it. After reviewing my code and trying a few other fixes I found out why my function was producing NaN.

```
const mysteryNumberObject = {
  mysteryNumber: 5,
};

function multiplyMysteryNumberByFive(mysteryNumberObject) {
  console.log(mysteryNumberObject.mysteryNumber * 5);
};

multiplyMysteryNumberByFive(mysteryNumberObject);
```

That line of code fixed the whole issue and I just switched the console.log to return after the debugging.